# Excel power query: how to replace a value but with a condition

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm new to power query, and I'm using the latest Excel (beta) release on Mac.

I currently have the following step:

> Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value2","payment_v2","-1",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"type - Copy"})

It works to replace all cells of the column where the value is "payment_v2" into "-1".

Good.

Now I want to add a condition to this formula. I'd like to first check if the column "payee" is "X", and if it's X I want to replace the value by "1", not "-1". But if it's not X, then I want to replace the value by "-1" as intended by the step above.

I've tried to look up conditional statements in power query, and I've attempted a few things, but nothing works. I can detail what I tried and what the errors were if requested, but my question is really "how to handle an if statement as part of that step?".

Thank you

Comment: There are numerous references on the internet and also on SO for replacing a value in a column based on another column.  If those don't help, please add data sample that can be copy/pasted, as well as what you have tried even if it hasn't worked. Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
= Table.ReplaceValue((#"Replaced Value2", each [#"type - Copy"], each if [#"type - Copy"] = "payment_v2" and [payee]="X" then "1" else if [#"type - Copy"] = "payment_v2" then "-1" else [#"type - Copy"], Replacer.ReplaceText, {"type - Copy"})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another column with the 1 for X and -1 for anything else, based on the same table and column as you used for your original replace, you can use this:

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value2", "Custom", each if [#"type-Copy"] = "X" then 1 else -1)
```

Or if you just want to update the original table and column you could try this instead:

```
Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value2", {"type-Copy", each if Text.Upper(_) = "X" then "1" else "-1"})
```

It transforms each cell in the type-Copy column based on whether the current entry is an X or not.

Comment: @Horseyride's answer is a better (more specific) match to your question than mine is.